# Substantif associé au verbe "cacher"

Tags: choix-de-mot, substantivation

Masquer donne masquage, dissimuler donne dissimulation. Cependant, je n'arrive pas à trouver de substantif à **cacher**. Je souhaite employer un tel mot dans un programme informatique, pour indiquer le fait de cacher des variables, et ni masquage, ni dissimulation ne me semblent appropriés.

Connaissez-vous un substantif proche de cacher pouvant être utilisé dans ce contexte, éventuellement un mot ancien  ?

Comment: "Dissimuler" est très proche de "cacher" dans ce sens je trouve. Quelle est la nuance qu'il faut apporter ? Qu'entends-tu par "cacher les variables" ? Soit les variables sont déclarées, soit elles le sont pas, je ne vois pas l'idée... :)

Comment: S'agit-il d'obfuscation ? Ou le fait de garder priver des variables et de ne pas les exposer aux autres classes ? (private vs public var)?

Comment: En fait dissimulation a, pour moi, une acception négative

Comment: @Larme Oui, dans ce sens. Mais apparemment mon usage d'obfuscation était un anglicisme.

Comment: Apparemment, Rabelais avait utiliser le verbe offusquer (avec deux "f" et sans "b" contrairement à l'anglais et à sa version informatique qu'on utilise), et Wiki semble donner du crédit à ça : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offuscation Après, personnellement, je n'ai absolument rien contre le fait d'utiliser des termes anglais en informatique.

Comment: @Larme Sauf meilleure proposition, offuscation me semble une réponse admissible

Comment: Est-ce une traduction du terme informatique anglais "obfuscation" que tu cherches ? Au sens de "rendre la rétro-ingénierie plus difficile" ?

Comment: J'éviterais d'utiliser _cacher_ dans le sens de _dissimuler_ en informatique: ce mot et ses dérivés y sont relatifs à la hiérarchie de la mémoire d'un ordinateur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quelques suggestions, chacune ayant ses propres connotations:

Escamotage

Mise en secret / mise en cachette

Camouflage

Answer (score 2):

S'il s'agit de « transformer une section de code ou un programme, de manière à le rendre totalement incompréhensible » ou de rendre le logiciel  « résistant à l'observation et à l'analyse  », on peut parler d'*[obscurcissement](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870389) (de code)*, voire d'*assombrissement* (GDT) ; on a aussi le [*brouillage*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=obfuscation&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) (Franceterme). Enfin hormis le [*secret*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/secret/71747?q=secret#70954) qu'on veut tenir caché et qu'on évoque [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/21958), on a aussi trouvé l'exemple usuel du *code (secret)*, inspirant la référence au [*codage*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/codage/16881?q=codage#16752) et au [*chiffrage*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/chiffrage/15320?q=chiffrage#15179), de sens plus usuels que ceux reliés à l'informatique, et qui peuvent peut-être aussi s'avérer utiles...